# MVC 4 Multi-tenant application connectionString

Tags: authentication, connection-string, multi-tenant

currently i am working on a multitenant application. I have single DB per tenant. Also i have a separate DB with one table containing tenantid, connection string and some other data. When a user logs in with a token, email and password, i am looking for a connectionstring and authenticate the user if exists. Thats working fine, but i have some issues when the user is authenticated and returns back to the site, after say 5 min, again.
How to retrieve the users connection string? My code for the authentication is as follows:

```
        DataModels.Tenant tenant = BLTenant.GetValidateTenant(token);

        if (tenant != null)
        {
            DataModels.User user = BLUser.GetValidateUser(tenant.TenantToken, email, password, tenant.TenantConnectionString);

            if (user != null)
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.UserName, rememberMe.HasValue ? rememberMe.Value : false);
                Session[ConstantsUtil.SessionUser] = user;
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("Login", "Login failed");
                return View("Login");
            }

        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("Login", "Login failed");
            return View("Login");
        }
```

As you can see i set the Session with the users data but dont know how to retrieve it after users come back. The session is then null...